# What does it mean that Jesus was a priest like the "Order of Melchizedek" in Hebrews 7:11?

Tags: hebrews, melchizedek

In Genesis 14 there is a man named Melchizedek. He is not mentioned very much and you might argue that he does not seem very important from this text alone.

> <sup>17</sup> After Abram returned from defeating Kedorlaomer and the
>   kings allied with him, the king of Sodom came out to meet him in the
>   Valley of Shaveh (that is, the King’s Valley). <sup>18</sup> Then
>   Melchizedek king of Salem brought out bread and wine. He was priest of
>   God Most High, <sup>19</sup> and he blessed Abram, saying, "Blessed be
>   Abram by God Most High, Creator of heaven and earth. <sup>20</sup>And
>   praise be to God Most High, who delivered your enemies into your
>   hand." Then Abram gave him a tenth of everything.
>
> (Genesis 14:17-20, NIV)

Except one of the Psalms, this is only one  place in the Hebrew Bible where he is mentioned at all.

> The Lord has sworn
>       and will not change his mind: "You are a priest forever,
>       in the order of Melchizedek."
>
> (Psalm 110:4, NIV)

In the Christian New testament he is, however, mentioned in the book of Hebrews a lot—and it seems like he is really important there. The author of Hebrews makes an argument that spans from chapter 5 to chapter 7 were Christ is compared to Melchizedek:

> <sup>5</sup> In the same way, Christ did not take on himself the glory
>   of becoming a high priest. But God said to him, "You are my Son; today
>   I have become your Father.” <sup>6</sup> And he says in another place,
>   "You are a priest forever, in the order of Melchizedek."
>
> (Hebrews 5:5-6, NIV)

Christ is said to be indirectly "in the order of Melchizedek" in Hebrews 7:

> <sup>7</sup>If perfection could have been attained through the
>   Levitical priesthood—and indeed the law given to the people
>   established that priesthood—**why was there still need for another
>   priest to come, one in the order of Melchizedek**, not in the order of
>   Aaron?
>
> (Hebrews 7:11, NIV, emphasis mine)

Why is Melchizedek such an important character for the author of Hebrews and what does it mean that Christ is "in the order of Melchizedek"?

<sup>Please note: This question originally contained two different questions. The second has since been [asked as a stand alone question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/7800/where-does-the-extra-information-about-melchizedek-come-from-in-hebrews-7).</sup>

Comment: I have asked a separate question for the secondary item asked about here so as to leave the focus of this question on the main question from the title. [Where does the extra information about Melchizedek come from in Hebrews 7?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/7800)

Comment: I agree that a priest in the order of Melchizedek means a priest in the order of being righteous before God and ministering to the nations the King/Priest of Salem ministered to Abram who later became the Father of Many Nations. Jesus ministered to all who called on His name during His earthly ministry. All this on addition to being an intercessor. Melchizedek and Jesus were both intercessors

Comment: The LDS Church has a different answer for this which might be of interest: https://www.lds.org/scriptures/gs/melchizedek?lang=eng, https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bd/melchizedek-priesthood, https://www.lds.org/scriptures/gs/melchizedek-priesthood

Comment: the name Melchizedek, like most Biblical names is also a regular word, in this case two words «Melech-Tzadik», meaning roughly «King-Priest». The significance of Jesus belonging to the order of king-priests, or holy-kings is that he, as the Messiah would ultimate replace both kingly and priestly orders existing at his times, by combining the two in himself.

Answer (score 8):

Historically there is a clear distinction between the king and the high priest. The first was always from the tribe of Judah and the second from the tribe of Levi. Even if there are examples of [kings that also were priests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Jannaeus), that was never an accepted order.

Still Jesus is claimed to be the Messiah (King):

> Jesus and his disciples went on to the villages around Caesarea
>   Philippi. On the way he asked them, “Who do people say I am?” They
>   replied, “Some say John the Baptist; others say Elijah; and still
>   others, one of the prophets.” “But what about you?” he asked. “Who do
>   you say I am?” Peter answered, “You are the Messiah.” (Mark 8:29, NIV)

AND the high priest:

> But when Christ came as high priest of the good things that are now
>   already here, he went through the greater and more perfect tabernacle
>   that is not made with human hands, that is to say, is not a part of
>   this creation. He did not enter by means of the blood of goats and
>   calves; but he entered the Most Holy Place once for all by his own
>   blood, thus obtaining eternal redemption. (Hebrews 9:11-12, NIV)

The author of Hebrews argue that the office of Jesus goes back even further than to David and Aaron, even further than Levi. It goes all the way back to Melchizedek which merged the two offices in one:

> Then Melchizedek king of Salem brought out bread and wine. He was
>   priest of God Most High (Genesis 14:18)

That way it was possible for Jesus to both be considered a priest and a king.

As a side note, Jesus was also from the tribe of Judah by his earthly father (Luke 2:4) and of the tribe of Levi on his mothers side<sup>1</sup> (Luke 1:5-6, 36).

These things were obviously very important for a Jew considering if Jesus was who the Christians claimed that he is.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is controversial. You might argue that Mary was from the tribe of Judah.

Answer (score 0):

What consistently gets overlooked in the story of Melchizedek is that He was not a Hebrew but a Canaanite, and the original priest King of Salem which we all know as Jerusalem.  He did not call God JHVH but El Elyon because he was a Canaanite.  The author of the book of Hebrews does not mince words in distinguishing Jesus as in the order of Melchizedek and not the Jewish priesthood.  That is why in His Kingdom we will not be restoring the Jewish sacrificial system to please God. We will be sharing Bread and Wine in celebration and not sacrifice. This also has eschatological significance since Daniel prophesied in chap. 7:18 in Aramaic (the language of Canaan) that the saints of El Elyon would inherit the Kingdom forever.  Not JHVH but El Elyon.

Comment: "...**Melchizedek** is that He **was not a Hebrew but a Canaanite**..." No, his nature does not allow for making claims about his descent. His origins are undefined.   **(Heb 7:3 YLT)**  **without father, without mother, without genealogy**, having **neither beginning** of days **nor end** of life, and being made like to the Son of God, doth remain a priest continually.

Comment: Interesting.  Jesus was human and a Jew aside from being the son of God.  Are you stating that Heb. 7:3 refers to Melchizedek as non human?  If so can we agree that Melchizedek was not a Jew?

Comment: Yes, as it is stated above in Hebrews, he, Melchizedek, by any lineage on earth, is not identifiable. His origins are unbounded, having neither beginning, or  end. He is likened unto the Son of God, specifically in terms of an eternal priesthood.

Comment: Is he not a Jew then?

Comment: Read up again please.

Comment: I am not trying to be terse, but I cannot be more explicit than I have already been. ;-)

Comment: Thank you.  I have had other "scholars" cite your literal interpretation of Hebrews 7:3 to point out that Melchizedek was not a Canaanite, yet refuse to state that he was not a Jew either, and I wanted to be clear that you were not one of them.  I do not hold to a little interpretation of Heb. 7:3 since I believe that Melchizedek was human and simply a mystery to the writer of Hebrews.

Comment: That is certainly your prerogative.

Comment: @sonofnoman You are correct. Melchizedek was a man and not a Jew. Abraham was the father of the Jews. Melchizadek was not his son, therefore, not a Jew. He was a man, and the author uses Rabbi Eliezer ben Jose de Galili's (2nd century) 26th rule: Mashal (parable) to make the interpretation. All of the OT history is considered to be a parable of Christ, which is why he says all speaks of him. In this parable, there is no record of M's birth or death, and so in the language of the riddle represents Jesus's record of no beginning or end.  It is parable; not literal.

Comment: Naturally the rabbi made his rule later, but is used here to show that it was a contemporaneous method of interpretation. He is one of the most quoted rabbis in ancient literature, yet was called a heretic. It is likely he is one of the four rabbis of the Pardes parable.

Answer (score -3):

In Hebrews 7:11 the KJV reads 'after the order of Melchisedec' while the NIV reads 'one in the order of Melchizedek'. In Hebrews 5:6 the KJV reads 'after the order of Melchisedec' while the NIV reads 'you are a priest forever in the order of Melchizedek'. In other words, the translators see "in the order" and "after the order" as meaning the same thing.

1. A priest in/after the order of Melchisedec is a priest who has not been made with hands, ie. natural birth,
2. Only one man has been promised that he is to be a priest forever after the order of Melchisedec. Ps. 110:4
3. 7:12 is the result. By changing the priesthood it also became mandatory to make a change of the law.

Since the man who is now serving in the office of high priest to his God is permanent there is no possibility of making another change of the law.
Therefore salvation can only be acquired, as a grant, by the faith of obeying this law.
"For it is not those who hear the law who are righteous in God's sight, but it is those who obey the law who will be declared righteous." Rom. 2:13

Comment: See Jn. 1:13 not by natural descent

Comment: This mostly makes sense in light of the texts, but there is a bit of a curve ball when you talk about "change of the law". It's not clear textually how you fit that in and the soteriological conclusion it takes you to is A) not really called for by this question and B) not consistent with the interpretive principles you've allowed to be used on the other verses.

Answer (score -5):

Melchizedek was a priest-king (symbolized in the priestly bread and kingly wine), a ministry which was a succession initiated by Noah: men who mediated for God but also had the power of the state (execution of murderers). Most importantly, this was a priesthood of all nations. All men were under the Noahic Covenant.

With the circumcision of Abraham, this changed. Symbolically, Adam was cut in two (hence the application of blood and oil to only one side of Aaronic priests). The Aaronic priesthood concerned only one nation, which would serve as mediator, making sacrifices for all other nations.

The death, resurrection and ascension of Christ completed this Aaronic ministry, and end the circumcision. The ministry of Christ in heaven is thus like that of Melchizedek, a priesthood of all nations. All men everywhere are called to repent - and once baptized may serve as witnesses for Christ.

Related to this is the fact that Aaronic priests always tipped out the wine. They could not drink it as kings in God's presence. This was case between Melchizedek's meeting with Abraham and the Last Supper.

Comment: Where does the Bible say Wine and Kings are linked? Thx

Comment: Melchizedek was a priest-king who brought bread and wine. So was Jesus. The process of humbling also follows the harvest year, with grain ripening first and grapes (and olives) later in the year, taking longer to mature and greater wisdom to produce. The grape haul in Numbers was a promise of the vineyards of Canaan, which could be possessed if Israel was faithful, and humbled with manna (bread). The theme goes back to the two trees in the garden, life (priestly humble dependance - bread) and judicial wisdom (kingly judgment).

Comment: @MikeBull-Hi Mike, I know we have gone around before, but you've got to show your work(like algebra), otherwise it sounds like you're in a trance. I know there is a body of commentary you can draw reference from explaining your view-and adding credence to it.

Comment: Yeah, but it would involve starting in Genesis 1 and following the theme's development right through the Bible, taking note of its placement in both the architecture and literary structure. The rules around here say you basically have to interpret one tile of the mosaic at a time. :) I can recommend James Jordan's "From Bread to Wine" and I have a chapter with diagrams on Melchizedek in my book "God's Kitchen."

Comment: Support is needed for the link between Noah and Melchizedek.

Comment: There are no Covenants made between Noah and Abraham, and Melchizedek is a priest-king like Noah (and possibly Job), somebody who stood to offer sacrifices but also sat in judgment.

Comment: As head of a new covenant, Noah was given the authority to take vengeance on God's behalf.
Monica, I do understand your exasperation, and I've basically given up posting on here. The artificial constraints are detrimental to actual biblical interpretation, and would be laughed at if required for the interpretation of any other literature. I can back up all my claims with the repeated structure found in the Bible. You have an amazing mind for the details (and I have really appreciated that) but if you are unwilling to put your finger on the pulse you are never going to "get it."

Comment: Sure, I understand. The process is based on a "cumulative reading" (as with any book) where meaning is conferred upon things and the text constantly makes references to previous events and their order (structure). I can't include that in every post.